# GNUradio: Order of float array UDP Sink receive is incorrect

Tags: udp, gnuradio

I'm currently working with GNU Radio, but i just find out something very weird.

The Order of Float Array that UDP receive is not the same with the one which Signal Source generated.

Here is the diagram of my GNURadio night now.

[image: flowgraph]

I use GUI Number Sink with Peak Hold to get the highest number, which is 1.9900126 after about 20s

But is my C# project which receives data via UDP, after i convert the first 4 received byte into float i got is 2.0000823, and the follow up flow is : 1.99992, 1.99991 ,... almost of half of my received float is higher than the Peak which GNU Number Sink holds.

Here is the code i use to convert received byte array to float:

```
listener = new UdpClient(ListenPort);
groupEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ListenPort);
var receiveByteArray = listener.Receive(ref groupEp);

if (receiveByteArray != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < receiveByteArray.Length / 4; i++)
    {
        fft[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(receiveByteArray, i * 4);
    }
}
```

So is my method of convert incorrect or the order of data received via UDP is incorrect ?

Comment: does the sending machine that receives the data have the same endianness as the .NET environment you're receiving with?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I test this on my local pc, so i think it should have the same endianness. But in the future, ill have the GNU run on Ubuntu and receive machine is android. I dont undestand endianness  much, what effect does its have on this ?